# Discover Meteor Microscope Share It Button

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, package, atmosphere.js

How would I add a "Share" button on the left of the "Discuss" button.  I wanted the button to be the same style/color as the current "Discuss" button.

I added the package from https://atmospherejs.com/joshowens/shareit

I added the {{>shareit}}  into the post_item.html.

```
<template name="postItem">
  <div class="post">
    <a href="#" class="upvote btn btn-default {{upvotedClass}}">$</a>
    <div class="post-content">
      <h3>{{title}}</h3>
      <p>
        {{pluralize votes "Vote"}},
        by {{author}},
        <a href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}">{{pluralize commentsCount "comment"}}</a>
        {{#if ownPost}}<a href="{{pathFor 'postEdit'}}">Edit</a>{{/if}}
      </p>
    </div>
    <a href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}" class="discuss btn btn-default">Reply</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is suppose to configure it.  Do I place it in the post.item.html?  If so, how?  I only want the twitter button.

```
ShareIt.configure({
useFB: true,          // boolean (default: true)
                      // Whether to show the Facebook button
useTwitter: true,     // boolean (default: true)
                      // Whether to show the Twitter button
useGoogle: true,      // boolean (default: true)
                      // Whether to show the Google+ button
classes: "large btn", // string (default: 'large btn')
                      // The classes that will be placed on the sharing buttons, bootstrap by default.
iconOnly: false,      // boolean (default: false)
                      // Don't put text on the sharing buttons
applyColors: true     // boolean (default: true)
                      // apply classes to inherit each social networks background color
});
```

Does this go in the post_item.js to enable any image cards?  I couldn't figure out how to put this in without errors.

```
Template.article.helpers({
  shareData: function() {
    return {
      title: this.data,
      author: Meteor.users.findOne(this.authorId)
  }
});
```

Here is the post_item.js file.

```
Template.postItem.helpers({
  ownPost: function() {
    return this.userId == Meteor.userId();
  },
  upvotedClass: function() {
    var userId = Meteor.userId();
    if (userId && !_.include(this.upvoters, userId)) {
      return 'btn-primary upvotable';
    } else {
      return 'disabled';
    }
  }
});
Template.postItem.events({
  'click .upvotable': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call('upvote', this._id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a template:

```
<template name="postItem">
    ...
    {{>shareIt shareData}}
</template>
```

Which means you also have a template object to match it somewhere:

```
Template.postItem
```

This is probably wrapped in something like the following:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.postItem.helpers({
        // your helper can hang out here:
        shareData: function() {
            return {
              title: this.data,
              author: Meteor.users.findOne(this.authorId)
            };
        };
    });
    // You can also put your ShareIt.configure here:
    ShareIt.configure({
        useFB: false,
        useTwitter: true,
        useGoogle: false,
        classes: "large btn",
        iconOnly: true,
        applyColors: true
    });
};
```

The above will also only display the twitter icon.

Now which files to put this in depends on your application structure. If you have a post_item.js and it is being send to the client (for example, it is in the client folders of your project, or it is not in a different special use folder of your project, as described here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) then the above should work for you. If you get errors, feel free to add them to the question so we can help!

Comment: Yes, I still get an error.  I added the post_submit.js file. @tim

Comment: Well I have no idea what post_submit is for. What error are you getting?

Comment: Oops, I put the wrong one in.  I put post_item.js in. See above.  I get "unexpected token error".  While building the application:
client/templates/posts/post_item.js:29:10: Unexpected token ;

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.  @tim

Comment: Well, that indicates you have a syntax error on line 29 of that file. However, the section you posted only has about 19 lines so, it's hard to debug. I would look somewhere before like 29 for a missing ";"

Comment: It was an extra ";" at line 29, fixed that part.  Now the post's are not all showing up.  The title field button on top are there but there are no posts.  Also, I get a yellow hyphen error that says "The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto creating".  This error is in the console. Would this affect the post's? @tim

Comment: These sorts of questions are rather hard to answer. Basically you're saying "My app doesn't work, can you tell me why?" Without having entire project to run, debug, and look at in both the console and the browser.

Comment: It worked w/ no bug w/ out the "Share It" package.  Once the "Share It" package was added, it showed the "fb-root" error.  Here is the Git  https://github.com/markleiber/so_30198019   @tim

Comment: It looks at though the ShareIt project has a number of issues at their repository about configuration especially as it pertains to Facebook. It seems you have to set up FB even if you aren't going to be using it.

Comment: Do I need to register on FB for the app setup?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3  @Tim

Comment: I got it working.  How do I move it to the right side and change the text in it? @Tim

Comment: Well, css. But no offense, that's a whole different question :) give it a try and if you have trouble then ask about your specific question.